# How to pull images from Airtable Database?

Tags: reactjs, airtable

When I try to compile my code, I get the error:

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vptcX.png)

I was following a tutorial and the only difference is the name of each column/field in Airtable. My project should be working but it isn't. Did I forget to declare something in particular? Is there an easier way to get images from Airtable? [React Airtable Tutorial](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/create-simple-web-app-react-airtable/?unapproved=337&moderation-hash=32571822cfa3a029f976755715e61eee#comment-325)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col, Card, CardImg, CardText, CardBody,
  CardTitle, CardSubtitle, Button } from 'reactstrap';
import './main.css';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      skills: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://api.airtable.com/v0/appXy4JgrvUicfB5F/Resources?api_key=keyE0exOkvaAnJeS0')
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then(data => {
       console.log(data);
       this.setState({ skills: data.records });
    }).catch(err => {
      // Error 
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Row>
          <Col>
            {this.state.skills.map(skill => <Roster {...skill.fields} /> )}
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default App;

const Roster = ({ Name, Service, LinkedIN, GitHub, Twitter, Facebook, Picture }) => (
      <div className="card">
        <div className="card-body">
          <img className="card-img-left" src={Picture[0].url} />
          <h5 className="card-title">{Name}</h5>
          <p className="card-subtitle">{Service}</p>
          <p className="card-text">
            <small className="text-muted"><a href={LinkedIN}><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a></small>&nbsp;
            <small className="text-muted"><a href={GitHub}><i class="fab fa-github-square"></i></a></small>&nbsp;
            <small className="text-muted"><a href={Twitter}><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a></small>&nbsp;
            <small className="text-muted"><a href={Facebook}><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a></small>&nbsp;
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Airtable API that you are using does not have a `Picture` property in for lots of objects and they are failing when trying to access `Picture[0]` because Picture is `undefined`.

If you do not have images for all objects, the easy way would be check if there is a `Picture` first before rendering:

```
{Picture && <img className="card-img-left" src={Picture[0].url} />}
```

[Demo on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-u1ewns?file=index.js)

Comment: I literally spent about 2 hours on this without getting anywhere. Clearly, I still need to go back and learn more about React. Thank you so much for your help. i truly appreciate it!